# CSS Circle border clipping around image

Tags: css, border

I am trying to add a circle outline (border) to a social icon which is a .svg file.
Making the sircle itself is not a problem, but the border creates an invisible layer over the picture itself, cutting off the corners, which I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a way to avoid this from happening, without altering the image itself?

I tried looking up the solution and tried multiple solutions, but none worked.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="image" name="submit" src="ic_youtube.svg" id="yt">
```

CSS Code:

```
input[type="image"]#yt {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid rgba(227, 227, 228, 1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 16px;
    margin-left: 254px;
    margin-top: 620px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[See the issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KabsN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the input in a div and add the border to the div instead. See what I did here:

```css
input[type="image"]#yt {
    width: 16px;
}

#iconContainer {
    position: absolute;
    border: 4px solid rgba(227, 227, 228, 1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 254px;
    margin-top: 620px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="iconContainer">
<input type="image" name="submit" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/9/e/4/13140637591549686593blue%20square.png" id="yt"> 
</div>
```

Comment: This did solve the clipping issue, thanks!
On a side note, since I had four of these Icons in a row, I had to use a different div id in css for each of them, but moving everything to the id's was easy enough.